# Android: simulate location changing using the emulator

Tags: android, location

I'm trying to understand how to emulate location with the emulator, using this [sample app](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/location/index.html) from the android documentation.
In the emulator control view of eclipse, I set the coordinates and press send, but nothing happen.

Am I forgetting something?

Comment: What values do you enter? Please give an example.

Comment: I tried various coordinates using both decimal and sexsagesimal notations. For example 0, 0.